# jQuery - Change action and form ID and use this

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, preventdefault

Apparently in the DOM have changed the values, even changed the ID of the form with the idea that the script no longer has effect but when you click Publish, nothing happens. Searching I tried to use "prop" instead of "attr" but it still does not work. I think it's because of the "e.preventDefault ()". But I do not know how to disable it. This is my code.
As you can see once the request is sent, the input and the "send" button are deactivated and when the values are received, they change the id of the form, the id and name of the button and it is renamed "Publish".

```
<script>
    jQuery(function($){
        var pluginUrl = '<?php echo plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ); ?>' ;
        $('[id^="form-search"]').on('submit', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                type : 'POST',
                url  : 'http://localhost/ladoserver/getapi.php',
                data : $(this).serialize(),
                cache: false,
                beforeSend: function(){
                    $('input#keyword').prop('disabled', true);
                    $('button#search').prop('disabled', true);
                    $('#resuls').html('<img src="'+pluginUrl+'../../assets/img/loading.gif" />');
                }
            }).done(function(data) {
                $('#results').html(data);
                $('input#keyword').prop('value', 'PUBLISH DATA');
                $('button#search').prop({disabled: false, id:'publish', name:'publish'}).html('Publish');
                $('span#help').hide();
                $('[id^="form-search"]').prop('action','publish.php');
                $('[id^="form-search"]').prop('id', 'form-publish'); 
                var countResults = $('input#total_data').val();
                for (var i = 1; i <= countResults; i++) {
                    $('#lista>select').clone().prop({ id: "cat_"+i, name: "cat_"+i}).appendTo('.category_'+i);
                }
                $('#lista').remove();
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Here my html

```
        <form action="" method="post" class="form-search" id="form-search">
            <fieldset>
                <!-- Form Name -->
                <legend>Name</legend>
                <div class="form-group">  
                  <input id="keyword" name="keyword" required="" type="text">  
                  <button id="search" name="search" class="btn btn-success boton">Search</button>
                  <span class="help-block" id="help">Help</span>
                    <div id="lista" style="display:none">Test</div>
                </div>
            </fieldset>
            <div id="result"></div>
        </form>
```

Here a fiddle showing that happened (check DOM).
[JSFiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/wujx3efp/1/)

Comment: can you post the html as well as your fiddle wont actually clarify what you want to achieve in the perspective of your currently posted code..

Comment: Ok, I'm added my html. As you can see once I get the results through AJAX, I change the "action" of the form, as well as the button (name and ID), thus becoming a "new" form. Now when I want to give the "Publish" button, this does not work, I should be redirected to the php script page.

Comment: ok..now from you code i can see that you are adding the action and id attributes to your form but again when the form is submitted where is the handler for it i mean you should add one more handler for form-publish action

Comment: I am amateur using jQuery, I thought that changing the form ID would be treated as a new one and activating the new Publish button would be processed as a normal form. How could I solve this?

Comment: ok .. i will add something to help..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
            //var pluginUrl = '<?php echo plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ); ?>' ;
            // when the action is plugin url.
            
            $(document).on('submit','[id^="form-search"]', function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $.ajax({
                    type : 'POST',
                    url  : 'http://localhost/ladoserver/getapi.php',
                    data : $(this).serialize(),
                    cache: false,
                    beforeSend: function(){
                        $('input#keyword').prop('disabled', true);
                        $('button#search').prop('disabled', true);
                        $('#resuls').html('<img src="'+pluginUrl+'../../assets/img/loading.gif" />');
                    }
                }).done(function(data) {
                    $('#results').html(data);
                    $('input#keyword').prop('value', 'PUBLISH DATA');
                    $('button#search').prop({disabled: false, id:'publish', name:'publish'}).html('Publish');
                    $('span#help').hide();
                    $('[id^="form-search"]').prop('action','publish.php');
                    $('[id^="form-search"]').prop('id', 'form-publish'); 
                    var countResults = $('input#total_data').val();
                    for (var i = 1; i <= countResults; i++) {
                        $('#lista>select').clone().prop({ id: "cat_"+i, name: "cat_"+i}).appendTo('.category_'+i);
                    }
                    $('#lista').remove();
                });
            });

    // when the action point to publish.php    === This is what you need

      $(document).on('submit','[id^="form-publish"]', function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var url = $(this).attr('action');
                $.ajax({
                    type : 'POST',
                    url  : url,
                    data : $(this).serialize(),
                    cache: false,
                    beforeSend: function(){
                        // do your pre-processing
                    }
                }).done(function(data) {
                    // do your post processing.
                });
            });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <form action="" method="post" class="form-search" id="form-search">
                <fieldset>
                    <!-- Form Name -->
                    <legend>Name</legend>
                    <div class="form-group">  
                      <input id="keyword" name="keyword" required="" type="text">  
                      <input type ="submit" id="search" name="search" class="btn btn-success boton">Search</button> 
    <!-- change the button type to submit type -->
                      <span class="help-block" id="help">Help</span>
                        <div id="lista" style="display:none">Test</div>
                    </div>
                </fieldset>
                <div id="result"></div>
            </form>
```

Comment: In the second action I must use AJAX to process my php file ?.
What happens if the action is a url?

Comment: not necessary to have ajax.. i just added it as your previous call was ajax so assumed you wish it to be ajax and the reason for being it done through js is because you dont have any submit button as you are using a button

Comment: if you dont want it ajax simply remove the second form submit handler and then submit the form it will submit to the new url

Comment: I actually thought that by changing the "send" button to "publish", the form would behave like a normal one that when giving the "Publish" button the "action = publish.php" will be executed.
Then what would I have to put inside: "$ ('[id ^ =" form-result "]'.) ('Submit', function (e) {}"?

Comment: ok.let me explain 
1) "where your form will submit the data depend upon the action url of form" as of in your code you can change the button search type to submit in that case it will add a default submit behavior 
2)now handling submit part we can do it manually as in your first case ( ajax to an url ) or let it have its default behavior ie. submit to action value.

now is that make sense to you??

Comment: Okay, but when I leave it by default and I give the "Publish" button. My button still behaves as if it were the form-search form. Why do I say this? Because to start the page does not go to publish.php and appears for a brief moment the gif of "loading ...", which was declared only for "id="form-search"" not for "id="form-publish"". Sorry if I'm slow to understand

Comment: ok so your problem is event delagation i will modify the code to help.. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XgppQa is pen that will clarify something to you! :D

Comment: Thank you very much for your time, my friend. Maybe the language barrier made it difficult for us to understand each other, I have tried the code that you proposed and making some adaptations to my own code, I made it work.
But I also have to tell you that I got what I needed originally by adding the following line: $('[id^="form-search"]').unbind('submit');

Comment: hey thats fine.. the main aim was to get it sorted and yea actually thats event delegation issue basically you need to rebind and bind it as you figured out a simple solution i guess could be the one i tried adding in pen https://jsfiddle.net/55jtbhe0/ .. anyways you have solution  :D :D